# Populate <div> when clicking a link, replace content when click another link

Tags: jquery

JS newbie ahead.

In short, this is what I want:
I click an `<a>` and a `<div>` is populated with text. I click another link and the text in the `<div>` is replaced and populated with a different text.

I have about 10 `<a>`s and 10 texts. I always want the newly clicked linked to replace any existing content.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Fill in the blanks please :) `... I click an XXX and a ZZZ is populated ...`

Comment: What have your tried so far? Can you post the HTML or a jsfiddle

Comment: Where is the content for the div coming from when someone clicks a link? It would help if you could post some code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#link_1_id').click(function(){
  $('#div_id').text('Content for clicking Link 1');
});
```

You should be able to use a map of link ID to texts in the above pattern to do what you want, or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/D4aS9/)

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#divresult').html($(this).text());
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

This will place the text inside the anchor into a div